# HttpPut peformance with Apache HttpClient in a multithread environment

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, httpclient

these days i'm struggling with a quite weird issue regarding Apache HttpClient and threads.

The point is that I have a HttpClient shared by all the threads and the use it to execute an HttpPut request to upload a small file (8k aprox.). Well with a small amount of threads everything is allright and the times are good (200-600 milliseconds), but when we start increasing the number of concurrent threads the times are awful (8 seconds).

We checked the server to ensure the problem wasn't there. Using jmeter with the same load (1000 threads in a second) we got response times of milliseconds!!

The implentation uses a thread-safe connection manager:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager httpConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
httpConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(5000);
httpConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5000);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
     .setConnectionManager(httpConnectionManager)
     .build();
```

And the threads run the following code:

```
HttpPut put = new HttpPut(urlStr);
put.setConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
     .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
     .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false)
     .setRedirectsEnabled(true).build());
put.setEntity(new FileEntity(new
            File("image.tif")));
put.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/tiff");
put.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(put, HttpClientContext.create());
```

It looks like if there was a shared resource that has a huge impact when there is a high load.

Looking at the sourcecode of Apache Jmeter I don't see relevant differences respect this code.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Which version of Apache HttpClient are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on debugging on the client side in order to do the following:

verify that the pool of 5000 is actually being used to great depth. The logger will display the changing totals for "available remain in pool" and the number of the current Pool entry being used.

verify that you are immediately clean-up and RETURN to pool the entry. Remember to close your resources ( Streams used to access response, Entity objects )

```
  CloseableHttpResponse response
    case PUT:
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
        httpPut.setProtocolVersion(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1,1));
        httpPut.setConfig(this.config);
        httpPut.setEntity(new StringEntity(data, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));                
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPut, context);
        httpPut.releaseConnection();
```

[More info](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout)